# Which relay module to buy and what is the difference between 1 channel and 2 channel relay boards

Tags: arduino-uno, relay, electronics, electricity

I wanted to d a simple circuit using Arduino to control the lights in my house. But i do not know which relay module to use my house runs on standard 220v ac.
Can anyone tell me weather this relay board will be enough

https://www.roboelements.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/1-Channel-5V-Relay-Module-for-Arduino-with-Optocoupler.jpg

Or should I buy a 2 channel one?
And another thing what is the difference between 1 channel and 2 channel relay board.

I'm a complete beginner, so please help me out.

Comment: A 1-channel relay board can switch one load, a 2-channel relay board can switch two loads independently. I don't want to sound patronizing but it looks like you have little experience with mains voltage. Please be very, very careful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use those. You have to watch a few things:

- Input voltage: 5V, perfect for Arduino
- Output voltage: 220 V, perfect for 220V AC
- Output amperage: 10A, what you control should use max 10 A, and I would use max 5A, and also consider switching on current into account. However, 10A is a lot of current.

The difference between 1 and 2 channels relay boards, is just that there are either 1 or 2 of them, meaning you can control 1 or 2 motors independently from each other.

Comment: really helpful ;))

Comment: Good luck with your project